# bash script concatenates input arguments with pipe xargs arguments

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute my script, but the $ 1 argument is concatenated with the arguments of the last pipe, resulting in the following

```
killProcess(){   
 ps aux |grep $1 | tr -s " " " " | awk "{printf \"%s \",\$2}" | tr " " "\n" | xargs -l1 echo $1
}
$killProcess node
node 18780
node 965856
node 18801
node 909028
node 19000
node 1407472
node 19028
node 583620
node 837
node 14804
node 841
node 14260
```

but I just want the list of pids, without the node argument to be able to delete them, that only happens when I put it under a script, in command line it works normally for me because I don't pass any arguments to the script and it doesn't get concatenated.

Comment: Just to be sure... What do you expect the $1 to stand for in the find command at the end of the line? You know that it will be 'node', and not the first field on the line generated by awk?

Comment: Also, sounds like you may be trying to reimplemented the equivalent of the killall command...

Comment: I know, I'm doing it for learning purposes.

Comment: $ 1 I want the pid of each process thrown at me, only when I execute it under the script, the argument passed to the process is concatenated, with the argument that picks up xargs.

, when I execute in the main shell, the argument is not concatenated as there is no $ 1 spent, everything was executed in the main shell.

Comment: Fair enough... Then replace the $1 in xargs by '{}' ';' (yes the syntax is weird...)

Comment: I managed to solve it but it is a bit strange, if I omit the $ 1 and just put in echo, by default I read the argument passed in xargs, however with {} it does not recognize me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you don't want the `$1` at the end. In that context, `$1` expands to the first argument to the function ("node", in your example), which then gets passed to `xargs` and treated as part of the command it should execute. That is, the last part of the pipeline expands to:

```
xargs -l1 echo node
```

...so when `xargs` receives "18780" as input, it runs `echo node 18780`, which of course prints "node 18780".

Solution: remove the `$1`, making the command just `xargs -l1 echo`, so when xargs receives "18780" as input, it runs `echo 18780`, which prints just "18780".

That'll fix it, but there's also a huge amount of simplification that can be done here. Many elements of the pipe aren't doing anything useful, or are working at cross purposes with each other.

Start with the last command in the pipe, `xargs`. It's taking in PIDs, one per line, and printing them one per line. It's not really doing anything at all (that I can see anyway), so just leave it off. (Unless, of course, you actually want to use `kill` instead of `echo` -- in that case, leave it on.)

Now look at the next two commands from the end:

```
awk "{printf \"%s \",\$2}" | tr " " "\n"`
```

Here, `awk` is printing the PIDs with a space after each one, and then `tr` is turning the spaces into newlines. Why not just have `awk` print each one with a newline to begin with? You don't even need `printf` for this, you can just use `print` since it automatically adds a newline. It's also simpler to pass the script to `awk` in single-quotes, so you don't have to escape the double-quotes, dollar sign, and (maybe) backslash. So any of these would work:

```
awk "{printf \"%s\\n\",\$2}"
awk '{printf "%s\n",$2}'
awk '{print $2}'
```

Naturally, I recommend the last one.

Now, about the command before `awk`: `tr -s " " " "`. This "squeezes" runs of spaces into single spaces, but that's not needed since `awk` treats runs of spaces as (single) field delimiters. So, again, leave that command out.

At this point, we're down to the following pipeline:

```
ps aux | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

There are two more things I'd recommend here. First, you should (almost) always have double-quotes around shell variable, parameter, etc references like `$1`. So use `grep "$1"` instead.

But don't do that, because `awk` is perfectly capable of searching; there's no need for both `grep` *and* `awk`. In fact, `awk` can be much more precise, searching only a specific field instead of the whole line. The downside is, it is a bit more complex to do, but knowing how to make `awk` do more complex things is useful. The best way to let `awk` work with a shell variable or parameter is to use its `-v` option to create an awk variable with the same value, and use that. You can then use the `~` to check for a regex match to the variable. Something like this:

```
awk -v proc="$1" '$11 ~ proc {print $2}'
```

Note: I'm assuming you want to search for `$1` in the executable name, and that that's the 11th field of `ps aux` on your system. Searching that field only will keep it from matching in e.g. the username (killing all of a user's processes because their name contains some program name isn't polite). You might actually want to be even more specific, so that e.g. trying to kill `node` doesn't accidentally kill `nodemon` as well; that'll be a matter of using more specific search patterns.

So, here's the final result:

```
killProcess(){
    ps aux | awk -v proc="$1" '$11 ~ proc {print $2}'
}
```

To actually kill the processes, add back `xargs -l1 kill` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see that you put points that I had not taken into account, I solved it by putting an alias with `xargs -l1 -I%`

Comment: If I know, I had forgotten to clean the command, since I was also testing it with cut, I know that awk doesn't need to replace the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know some awk functions.